# How to add new class to existing edmx file

Tags: entity-framework

Assume that I have added a product table into sql server DB. How to generate product class to existing edmx file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to update your edmx file right click on the screen and Click on Update Model From Database. then a window will come select you table from the tables and follow the wizard.
when you finish the wizard then you will find your selected table entity in the edmx and the generated class will b in yourmodel.tt file

then you have to go to the youmodel.context file and make property for the new class like

```
public DbSet<yourClass> ex { get; set; }
```

and then you good to go

for ref follow the [Link](http://praveenbattula.blogspot.ae/2009/10/how-to-drag-and-drop-entities-from.html)

Comment: @Developerzzz-But no generated class in tt file. Why? VS2012

Comment: After add table in edmx file from your database , you have to update again that edmx file, and this time select only refresh tag for update, then table1.cs will create automatically

Comment: I think you should run migration to update database with your existing class (make sure they appear in database by adding the above line of code), then update edmx from database.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you add a new table to you database, you need to update you Edmx. For that simply open you edmx and right click --> select update model form database and select you newly added table and then click finish. Your model will be updated and new classes will be automatically added.

Comment: No DbSet like `public DbSet<EMPLOYEE> EMPLOYEE { get; set; }`

Comment: No new class generate